I need help if the epsilon-delta problem I solved is correct.
enter image description here
I need to solve this with epsilon-delta; are the things I wrote correct?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Related to Prove that lim (x,y)-(-1,1) =0 by using ephilon-delta method?

I think you made the same mistake at two places:
At $\sqrt{x^2} \le \sqrt{(x+1)^2}$. This is incorrect because it means $|x| \le |x+1|$. But this is false if $x = - 0.99$. The other place is at $\sqrt{y^2} \le \sqrt{(y-1)^2}$. This is also false since it means $|y| \le |y-1|$ as it is false for $y = 0.99$. What you need is $|x+y| \le |x+1|+|y-1|\le 2\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2}$. From this, we can proceed to the finish line. So let $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then if $|(x,y) - (-1,1)| < \delta$, which means $\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2} < \delta$, then $|x+y| < 2\delta = 2\cdot \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$.

Can you please help me a little more? I tried to finish it but couldn't.

I get it now,thank you VERY much for your help!!!
